Singular value of a bidiagonal matrix?
Consider a $n\times n$ matrix:
\begin{equation}
X=\begin{bmatrix}
a &1-a & & \\
  & a &1-a & \\
 & & \ddots &\\
& & & 1-a\\
& & & a
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $a\in(0,1)$. Is it any way to calculate its singular values?
Here is my thought: I know it's easy to check all of its eigenvalues equal to $a$, but it seems non-trivial to calculate eigenvalues of $XX^\top $ (which is equivalent to square of singular values of $X$).

$A=XX^{\top}$ is a tridiagonal matrix, and its eigenvalues can be calculated. You can try to solve $Ax=\lambda x$.

@MakaBaka, indeed one can do this. But exact value of it is still highly non-trivial. Actually any approximation would help.

The matrix $X X^\top$ is almost a Toeplitz matrix in addition to being tridiagonal. That is, its elements are nearly identical along the diagonal. But the matrix element in the lower-right corner of $XX^\top$ is different than the rest along the diagonal, which spoils this. (It's close enough that this still may be useful: adjusting one diagonal element is a rank-one update.)

Also, the case $a=1/2$ seems (empirically) to have singular values $\cos(\pi k/(2n+1))$ for $k=1,2,\ldots, n$. This seems likely to be known already.

We can calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of tridiagonal matrix directly. Set $A=XX^{\top}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha&\beta&&\\
\beta&\alpha&\beta&\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&\beta&\alpha
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where
$$
\alpha=a^2+(1-a)^2,\quad \beta=a(1-a).
$$
For $Ax=\lambda x$, where $x\neq0$, $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^{\top}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$
(\ast)\qquad\beta x_{k+1}+(\alpha-\lambda)x_k+\beta x_{k-1}=0,\quad k=1,\cdots,n.
$$
Here $x_0=x_{n+1}=0$.
The solution of $(\ast)$ can be written as
$$
x_k=C_1\mu_1^k+C_2\mu_2^k,\quad k=1,\cdots,n,
$$
where $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are two roots of the characteristic equation w.r.t. $(\ast)$
$$
\beta\mu^2+(\alpha-\lambda)\mu+\beta=0.
$$
It can be easily verified that $\mu_1\neq\mu_2$. So
$$
(\ast\ast)\qquad\mu_1+\mu_2=-\frac{\alpha-\lambda}{\beta},\quad \mu_1\mu_2=1.
$$
Since $x_0=x_{n+1}=0$, we have
$$
C_1+C_2=0,\quad C_1\mu_1^{n+1}+C_2\mu_2^{n+1}=0,
$$
and
$$
\left(\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}\right)^{n+1}=1\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}=e^{2\mathrm{i}j\pi/(n+1)},\quad j=1,\cdots,n.
$$
Note that it have $n$ pair roots $\mu_1^{(j)},\mu_2^{(j)}$. Along with $(\ast\ast)$ we can get all eigenvalues of $A$
$$
\lambda^{(j)}=\alpha+2\beta\cos\frac{j\pi}{n+1},\quad j=1,\cdots,n,
$$
and corresponding eigenvector is
$$
x^{(j)}=(\sin\frac{j\pi}{n+1},\sin\frac{2j\pi}{n+1},\cdots,\sin\frac{nj\pi}{n+1})^{\top}.
$$
For singular value of $X$, just take a square root.

As a side note, there is a paper with a theorem talking about this, check theorem 2.2 of "Eigenvalues of tridiagonal pseudo-toeplitz matrices,”, url: https://hal.science/hal-01461924/document
